# Check apache modwsgi reload is working correctly

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I deployed a application a while ago and it is currently in production. I learned about and attempted to set up code reloading. [I read and followed the documentation.](https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode) and now I'm looking for a way to check to see if I have configured everything correctly without making an obvious change to the production website.

How can I go about testing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clone a production environment to a test environment and do all the testing and checking there.

If use sane approach to things and application is deployed in production, never do tests, checks on it, unless required when troubleshooting the application stack in the middle of the night. Please make it a habit. It makes live of sysadmins and ops so much easier when developers do not go after deployment and say:

"Listen bro can i hop on that prod server we rolled out an app to yesterday pretty quick, it seems I forgot to check one minor thing". - This believe me leads to all kind of problems. Advising from lots of similar situations.

Comment: Alright, the production servers on a VM so this will actually be pretty simple to do. I'll just make a clone and set up a new host name. This feels pretty obvious (in a "ooooooh... crap" kind of way) now that you've said it.

Comment: Do not forget change the hostname and ip addressing, I also tend to have isolated vlans for dev, test just for sanity sake.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the background code monitor given at the end of that document in production.

Either way, you can see whether mod_wsgi restarts processes because of code changes by ensuring that LogLevel in Apache is set to 'info'. Then check the Apache error log.